# Same instance referred to by multiple constructors

Tags: java, instance

I have an instance of Class A that I want to refer to in the constructor of multiple instances of B. How can I refer to that particular instance of Class A in each new instance of B?

Comment: The spec for the constructor signature requires me not to pass it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only ever want to have one instance of class A, use a [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).  You can then have class B's constructor refer to the singleton.  Otherwise, the best way to refer to an object of class A in the constructor of class B is to pass it as an argument.

Comment: I forgot to add i can't pass it as an argument. Good solution. 

Thanks.